# Java compiler builds inefficient code for string concatination?

Tags: java, performance, javac, string-concatenation

I thought that this is the most efficient way to concatinate strings

```
new StringBuilder(s1.length() + s2.length() + s3.length()).append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).toString();
```

here StringBuilder's buffer is created with the capacity enough to fit all strings in it, otherwise StringBuilder may need to expand the buffer up to 3 times.

But when I compile / decompile this

```
String s4 = s1 + s2 + s3;
```

I get the actual code in .class built by javac (1.7.0_03) as

```
String s4 = (new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(s1))).append(s2).append(s3).toString();
```

Which way is more efficient?

**UPDATE**

As it was suggested by Steven Schlansker, here is a performance test

```
                String s1 = "0123456789";
                String s2 = s1 + s1 + s1;
                String s3 = s1 + s1 + s1 + s1 + s1 + s1;
                long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {

                String s4 = new StringBuilder(s1.length() + s2.length() + s3.length()).append(s1).append(s2).append(s3).toString();

//          String s4 = s1 + s2 + s3;

                }
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t0);
```

it's not perfect, but the results seem to prove that my version is ~30% faster. On my notebook (Celeron 925) it gives ~230 ms for ver.1 aganist ~300 ms for ver.2. Actually this is what I expected. So I think it would be a good idea if javac compiled string concatination in a more efficient way. There are enough lines like

```
return "\\Q" + s + "\\E";
```

even in JDK classes. The last line is from java.util.Pattern which is designed for efficiency

Comment: If it's efficiency you want, I would use `Pattern.compile(s, Pattern.LITERAL);`  This would only have to done once per string `s`, avoids both creating a StringBuilder and having to parse the String.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on the environment you execute it in.  It's not possible to conclude definitely that one is better than the other without some sort of test.

That said, I agree that it's likely that knowing the final size ahead of time will provide some benefit.

I suspect that if you write a microbenchmark, you'll find that the difference is absolutely trivial in almost any application.

EDIT FOR BENCHMARK ADVICE:

I see you've added some actual data to your post.  Congratulations!  You're on the right track :-)

Unfortunately, Java has many features which are hostile to writing correct benchmarks.  You should probably take a look at [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) if you want your results to be accurate.  It's also worth considering that speedups that look large in this context will look much smaller in the context of a "real" program.  A single database fetch (measured in milliseconds) could easily make any gains in memory allocation completely uninteresting (measured in nanoseconds).